# ROR email app with custom fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Ruby on Rails application which allows users to write emails and include fields such as customer name, address, etc. which will be dynamically drawn from our database.

A user would optimally be able to write text into a from, and press a button for "add name", which would then add something like <%= name %> into the form and when being sent would actually contain the customer name.

My question is really what approach is the best to start this - specifically how to parse and store the data. Should I somehow try to parse the form into an array and store as separate fields in a database?
or is it better to store in a text field and parse the message out later when it's being sent. Is there a Gem or some kind of common technique for this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is store the email with placeholders in the database, then parse before it is sent. When a user hits "add name", you should inject something like `{name}`, not ERB. Then  the emails you store will look like:

> Hi {name}, etc etc

This could all be packaged into an `Email` model:

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessible :subject, :body

  def placeholders
    {
      "name" => user.name,
      "subject" => subject,
      "footer" => user.email_footer
    }
  end

  def parsed_email
    email = body.dup
    placeholders.each { |key, val| email.gsub!("{#{key}}", val) } 
    email
  end

end
```